# Translation for "Ok, got it!"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am looking for some common sentences that can be easily used in a conversation. Right now I came across : "Einverstanden" and "Alles klar", and I am wondering if these both could translate the expression "Ok, got it!". What would be the difference between those two expressions then? 
Would there maybe be different ways to express this depending on the area we are in?

Comment: I might use "Alles klar" for "Ok, got it". It is pretty versatile. "Einverstanden" is  more like "I find that acceptable."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The direct translation would be "OK, verstanden". "Alles klar" is just as good in my opinion. "Einverstanden" would not be the best option. This would translate back to "Agreed", so has a different meaning.

Comment: So Einverstanden would be more appropriate after making a deal or somthing, right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It would be a response at the end of a negotiation or the answer to a suggestion.

Comment: "Kapiert" would also be good (if informal) answer, if the scenario is, that the recipient understands a possibly difficult argumentation or scenario,

Answer (score 1):

In another context: If you were looking for something and found it you can say "Ok, ich habs".

Comment: which context? what do you mean?

Comment: @Elisabetta In the context he mentions "if you were looking for something and you've found just it", then you say "OK, I got it" meaning "I found it" -> "OK, ich hab's (gefunden)"